# timestamp ecact time calculate

Tags: python, sql

this this timestamp from one of website
but this timestamp always have few members extra if someone can tell me what is this and why

```
ex - 01. "timestamp" : 1639372212465
ex - 02. "timestamp" : 1639372222538 
ex - 03. "timestamp" : 1639372231569
ex - 04. "timestamp" : 1639372255578
ex - 05. "timestamp" : 1639372268624
ex - 06. "timestamp" : 1639372277634
```

this  `timestamp` example mentioned by real order, if someone can tell me what is the relations between those numbers

Answer (score 0):

This is just a milliseconds measurement from Epoch Unix Time rather than seconds (which might explain the extra digits). Basically each timestamp in the examples is the number of milliseconds from Jan 1st, 1970 UTC.

You can put in some of the numbers into this [unix timestamp tool](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php).

And for `1639372212465`, you'll get something like

```
Format   Milliseconds (1/1,000 second)
GMT      Mon Dec 13 2021 05:10:12 GMT+0000
Your     Time Zone  Sun Dec 12 2021 21:10:12 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Relative 10 minutes ago
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually this is one of gambling website crash game timestrap. if there any way to predict the crash time using this ?

Comment: You might be able to try to see the difference in each timestamp and see if you can see a pattern, but usually you'd want more information/features (e.g. server load or workload) in order to predict that sort of things.

Comment: can you do it,if it is what is the charges ?